# C++ std::unordered_map slower than std::map?

Tags: c++, stl

In the example below I was expecting `unordered_map` to be faster than `map`, but it's not the case. Why is it so? Is `unordered_map` designed for another purpose than being faster than the regular map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, double> grid_unmap_int;
    std::map<int, double> grid_map_int;
    
    size_t map_size = 1e7;

    auto t1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map_size; ++i) {
        grid_unmap_int[i] = 1.0;
    }
    auto t2 = clock();


    for (size_t k = 0; k < map_size; ++k) {
        grid_map_int[k] = 1.0;
    }
    auto t3 = clock();

    std::cout << "Insertion \n";
    std::cout << "Filling unordered map int key: " << (t2 - t1) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds.\n";
    std::cout << "Filling map int key: " << (t3 - t2) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds.\n";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    t1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < map_size; ++i) {
        double b = grid_unmap_int[i] ;
    }
    t2 = clock();


    for (size_t k = 0; k < map_size; ++k) {
        double b = grid_map_int[k];
    }
    t3 = clock();

    std::cout << "Retrieve \n";
    std::cout << "Filling unordered map int key: " << (t2 - t1) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds.\n";
    std::cout << "Filling map int key: " << (t3 - t2) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " seconds.\n";


    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
the results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVaX9.jpg)

Comment: `unordered_map` is not designed to be *faster* then a regular map. They work differently. Just like a vector or list. You can't call one of them *fastest* or *best*. They have strong and weak sides, and which one to use depends on your use-case.

Comment: You are making a claim about performance without providing statistics or compilation flags.

Comment: quick-bench suggests that in-fact unordered_map is 5x faster for your particular test case: https://quick-bench.com/q/OK0XfUYBuko17quF1edWLIgLdK8

Comment: Your claim seems to be in conflict with what's written on cppreference. [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) - *Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity.* [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) - *Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity.*

Comment: @super what would be a reason to use unordered_map instead of map if it isn't designed to be faster? That's the only reason to use it, and it is designed to be faster.

Comment: Did you use `-O3`?  On my system, unordered_map is x2.8 faster for insertion, and x10 faster for retrieve.

Comment: I'm not seeing the results you are.  [Your code shows much better performance for `unordered_map`](https://godbolt.org/z/EKTqGPPMW).  Were you perhaps profiling a debug build?  (Note: `1e7` changed to `1e6` so as not to blow up the sandbox)

Comment: The godbolt and quick-bench results are for size 1e6 not 1e7. If OP is actually able to run 1e7 without crashing, perhaps the result is different, but such a gigantic container definitely counts as an edge case.

Comment: @freakish It's designed to have faster lookup-speed, so that would be the reason to use it. It's not just magically faster in general. If that was the case, then why would the normal map exist at all?

Comment: @super the OP is precisely measuring inserts and lookups. These are designed to be faster with unordered_map. Map on the other hand has other advantages: since it is ordered you can do efficient "get range", "get smaller than", "get greater than" kind of lookups, which are not even available on unordered_map.

Comment: @Passerby so the 1e6 vs 1e7 may actually be a hint of what's going on. Assuming OP is not wrong, the only explanation I can see is that he has lots of hash collisions at this level, which typical unordered_map handles as linear scan. That would be interesting to verify.

Comment: cachegrind shows a lot of cache misses on the `unmap` lines. If OP's CPU has a small cache (or slow RAM?), the non-local access patterns of unordered map could be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

> In the example below I was expecting `unordered_map` to be faster than `map`, but it's not the case. Why is it so?

That can be the case, as `std::map` promises [logarithmic lookup time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), while `std::ordered_map` promises [constant lookup time on average, worst case linear in the size of the container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at).

Which is a fancy way of saying "It could be better, and it could be worse.  Profile it for your specific scenario".

> Is `unordered_map` designed for another purpose than being faster than the regular `map`?

Yes.

`std::map` can only use keys that are **ordered**.  There must be an established way to sort the type, like the `int` in your example.  And in return, iterating the `std::map` gives you that ordering.

`std::unordered_map` can only use keys for which [`std::hash<Key>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is defined.  The keys do not need to have an established ordering (They could be images, for example.  Or colors.  Or sounds.)  But there must exist some  way to convert the values to hashes.

Comment: Actually complexity doesn't tell us much at all. O(exp(n)) can be faster than O(1) for all achievable n (e.g. n <= max memory size) if the latter has some huge constant associated. And this is not some abstract argument. That's the reason why for example quicksort is widely used even though there are algorithms with better complexity (e.g. merge sort).

Comment: @freakish you're absolutely right.  Complexity tries to describe _scalability_, not _speed_.  Which itself blows up if scaling up happens to change O(1) to O(n).

Comment: My point is that there are still some expectations about performance, regardless of complexity. Especially in this case. I know there are no guarantees, but almost everyone will use map instead of unordered_map without measuring, when ordering is not needed. Also about ordering: actually all objects can be ordered. After all every object is represented as some number. Potentially huge like for example an image, but still a number.

Comment: @freakish you are welcome to edit this answer if any phrasing does not seem right to you.  I may not have been clear enough about "having an ordering" being different from whether it is possible to order.